# Control de sesiones y accesos de usuarios

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5

Saludos a todos y quisiera realizar una pregunta para que me guíen con la investigación y solución al siguiente tema:

- Actualmente mantengo un aplicativo en la web construido con PHP, javascript y HTML5 el cual gestiono sesiones a los usuarios el momento de su acceso y de igual manera un período de inactividad de 15 minutos que provoca que el usuario vuelva a loguearse
- Requiero validar si el usuario se loguea ya sea de 2 computadores diferentes, 2 dispositivos diferentes o en un computador y un dispositivo que la ultima session o el ultimo acceso termine con el anterior acceso para que no pueda manntenerse dentro del sistema en diferentes dispositivos, solo puede mantenerse en uno, en este caso el ultimo donde se logueo.

Esperando la guia correspondiente.

Comment: https://www.uno-de-piera.com/evitar-inicios-sesion-duplicados-php/ aqui se explica como evitar el inciio de sesión duplicado, espero te sirva.

Comment: hice la implementación del ejemplo pero me nace una duda, puesto que siempre que ingresas al sistema el te actualiza la sesion en la BDD y cuando ingresas a otra pantalla valida la que genero entonces nunca va a existir una desigualdad entre la generada y registrada y entre la nuevamente obtenida para ver su igualdad o validar...